# Python, how to import all images from directory?

Tags: python

I have problems with importing jpg files in my directory.
I used code below, but when i run im.show(), it says im is not defined.
Also, nothing is shown for print(filename)
what should i do to solve this problem?

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('C:Users\Ivans\dataset\*.jpg'): 
    print(filename)
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

Comment: it's possible that your glob is not getting any files. I would check your path is correct, maybe use pathlib to help you with handling with paths

Comment: I would use, os.listdir() to list all your images.

Comment: Either use `r"C:Users..."` or escape the backslashes. The `glob` might read a different path than what you think you pas to it... Also I believe it should be `C:\\Users...`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is correct but you can try using `os.listdir`

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

image_list = []

dir = 'dir'
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    print(filename)
    im=Image.open(f"{dir}/{filename}")
    image_list.append(im)
```

Comment: yeah i fixed it

Comment: No I mean, if you don't think it's correct don't post it. Check your code and make sure it works. Or at least don't write that in your answer...

Comment: Anyway looks correct to me... Maybe I would prefer to use `filename = os.path.join(dir, filename)` instead of string formatting

Comment: Also note that the OP code is only iterating over `.jpg` files, so you might want to add an `if filename.endswith("jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows backslashes, consider using a raw string to avoid parsing escaped characters, i.e.

```
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:Users\Ivans\dataset\*.jpg'):
```